# How to return "finished" section of a javascript code

Tags: javascript

I want to upload an image file to server and then show it on browser editor on return.

For that, I have **#fileInput** form input (type file) to upload an **image** to server.

On change **#fileInput**, I trigger **uploadAndReadURLfunction** which calls **app.uploader** for upload.

When upload is finished, it returns to line commented "Coming here" below. However, I want it to return to the line commented "Not coming here". How can I make this happen.

```js
var app = app ||  {};

(function(o) {
  "use strict";

  var ajax, getFormData;

  ajax = function(data) {
      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;

      xmlhttp.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4) {
          if(this.status === 200) {
            var res =this.response;

            if(res == 1) {
              console.log(res);  // Coming here.                  
            }
            
          }
        }
      });

      xmlhttp.open('post', o.options.processor);
      xmlhttp.send(data);
  };

  getFormData = function(source) {
      var data = new FormData(), i;

      for(i = 0; i < source.files.files.length; i = i + 1) {
          data.append('file[]', source.files.files[i]);
      }

      data.append('ajax', true);

      return data;
  };

  o.uploader = function(options) {
    o.options = options;

    if(o.options.files !== undefined) {
        ajax(getFormData(o.options));
       
    }
  }

}(app));





function uploadAndReadURL(input) {
  if(input.files && input.files[0]) {

    var f = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    
    app.uploader({
      files: f,
      processor: "/geornal/image",

      finished: function(data) {

        console.log("burada2.");     // Not coming here..
      },

      error: function() {
        console.log('Not working');
      }
    });
  }
}



$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#icerik2").on("change", "#fileInput", function(){
    uploadAndReadURL(this);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would `res` equal `1` ? What is expected value of `this.response` ?

Comment: On success, I return 1 from server.

Comment: Where is `finished` called ? Tried substituting `responseText`  for `this.response` ?

Comment: There is "finished:" section in uploadAndReadURL function. I don't know how to call "finished" from app function.

Comment: `if(res == 1) {
              o.options.finished(res);           
            }
` ?

Comment: Yes, it is coming now :) Thank you. I think I can' understand basics of js. Could you recommend me something to read?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108041/discussion-between-user2356198-and-guest271314).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There is "finished:" section in uploadAndReadURL function. I don't
>   know how to call "finished" from app function.

Try calling `o.options.finished()` at `if` statement within `readystatechange` handler

```
if(res == 1) { o.options.finished(res); }
```